# Automated Electron desktop application is not working in Electron version 4.0 which is worked on version 2.0

Tags: java, c#, selenium-webdriver, electron

I have automated Electron(Version 2.0) application and it was running successfully. Recently dev team updated Electron version from 2.0 to 4.0. My Selenium script is opening the application but not performing any operation on the Application. It's not clicking any of the elements.

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour] and see [ask], then [edit] your question accordingly. You'll get much better help from our volunteers.

Comment: I have automated .exe application using Selenium WebDriver, C# and Java also. In my existing .exe application developed with Electron version 2.0 and my automation scripts are working fine. Recently .exe application updated with Electron version 4.0. In that my script is opening .exe application but not performing any operation. Its not clicking the elements